# require cannot load such file

Tags: ruby, tdd

I have the following 2 files in the same dir:

**churn.rb:**

```
 subsystem_names = ['audit', 'fulfillment', 'persistence',    
                     'ui', 'util', 'inventory']
  start_date = month_before(Time.now)       

  puts header(start_date)                   
  subsystem_names.each do | name |
    puts subsystem_line(name, change_count_for(name))   
  end
```

**churn_test.rb:**

```
require "test/unit"
require "churn"    

class ChurnTests < Test::Unit::TestCase 

  def test_month_before_is_28_days
    assert_equal(Time.local(2005, 1, 1),
                 month_before(Time.local(2005, 1, 29)))
  end

end
```

When I run `churn_test.rb` I get the following error:

```
/Users/ca/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- churn (LoadError)
    from /Users/ca/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from churn-tests.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `require sth`, Ruby searches the source in `$LOAD_PATH` (`$:`). For security concern, the current working directory is not included in `$LOAD_PATH`. You can either explicitly add the directory into `$LOAD_PATH`

```
$: << File.dirname(__FILE__)

require 'churn'
```

or use the [`Kernel#require_relative`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative) to require a module based on the same directory:

```
require_relative "churn"
```

Comment: How can I reconfigure some file to add current working directory into ruby $LOAD_PATH

Comment: @PeterZhu try adding `$: << "."` to the beginning of those file